# Wordpress postboxes On Tabbed Views and Hiding Registered Pages

Tags: plugin-development

Firstly here is a YouTube of me explaining my problem...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nenu1stzLRw

I want to be able to use postboxes on tabbed pages. Usually tabbed pages are called views to avoid confusion with actual admin registered pages. I have around 5 plugin pages and each has a tab menu. I cannot use postboxes full ability on them because each tab/view shares the same settings registered for the WP admin page they are on. So one page, multiple views.

Wordpress does not appear to have a parameter to create settings per tab/view as it relies on the "page" variable in the URL which is always for a registered page. So I've went ahead and registered all of my views. Around 30 and I want to hide 25 of them say. The 5 left will show menus allowing access to the rest of my plugins admin pages. That is my attempt at a solution but it does not work.

This is the function that prevents postboxes being used properly on tabbed views...

```
function wp_ajax_meta_box_order() {
check_ajax_referer( 'meta-box-order' );
$order = isset( $_POST['order'] ) ? (array) $_POST['order'] : false;
$page_columns = isset( $_POST['page_columns'] ) ? $_POST['page_columns'] : 'auto';

if ( $page_columns != 'auto' )
    $page_columns = (int) $page_columns;

$page = isset( $_POST['page'] ) ? $_POST['page'] : '';

if ( $page != sanitize_key( $page ) )
    wp_die( 0 );

if ( ! $user = wp_get_current_user() )
    wp_die( -1 );

if ( $order )
    update_user_option($user->ID, "meta-box-order_$page", $order, true);

if ( $page_columns )
    update_user_option($user->ID, "screen_layout_$page", $page_columns, true);

wp_die( 1 );
```

TablePress
See the TablePress plugin for an example of what I DO NOT want my plugin to do. I want the tab menu but I do not want the tabs to be reflected in the main plugin menus and vice-versa. This plugin is great coding standards and makes perfect use of the WP core but I'm trying to improve on it. If I could do it the TablePress plugin could have a single page.

Comment: Why are you bypassing the register function?

Comment: What exactly are the "Views" you are talking about? Is this a plugin or theme related question?

Comment: @kiaser, I believe this is the Plugin he's working on: [CSV 2 POST](https://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-2-post/)

Comment: Wordpress being a CMS admin pages are a big deal in the code. "page" is used a lot in the PHP. A plugin can have many pages and on each page a menu of tags. You might actually refer to each view as a tab as I have seen done but what do you call a tab if you call the view/screen a tab?

Comment: I did not link to CSV 2 POST on Wordpress.org because there is no version on there that demonstrates what I am doing. TablePress is a great plugin, very well coded and has perfect Wordpress standards. That does some of what I'm trying to achieve but only does it for the page, no views within a page. I'm trying to take it further and I don't think it's possible with "views" simply being tabbed content. I think I need to register as much as 35 views as pages. Meaning no more "views" confusion just lots of pages. Then I need to hide most of those pages from the Wordpress plugin menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following:

```
$metabox_array = array (array('view1', 'Metabox for View 1', 'Render View 1', 'Post', 'normal', 'default',
                              'view2', 'Metabox for View 2', 'Render View 2', 'Post', 'normal', 'default',
                              'view_x', 'Metabox for View_x', 'Render View_x', 'Post', 'normal', 'default',));
    function adding_custom_meta_boxes( $post ) {
    add_meta_box($metabox_array);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes' );
```

As kiaser states though, we need more information.

Comment: Thanks and I know your short of information but this I have done. It's hard to show you guys because it's not a small project. Two classes, I think possibly three are used in making this happen up to the point the posts boxes can be moved around, hidden etc.